# how to display popup methods for Excel objects in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I am working with access 2010 and writing so VBA code.
My problem is that when I write the object name and a dot, the method list for this kind of object does not appear. With other types of objects such as recordset is fine.
I believe the problem is that I do not declare the objects, but just set them as follows:

```
Set ExcelFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Wbook = ExcelFile.Workbooks.Add
Set Wsheet = Wbook.Worksheets.Add
```

and the following do not work

```
Dim ExcelFile As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

or

```
Dim ExcelFile As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
```

or

```
 Dim ExcelFile As Object
```

and

```
 Dim Wsheet1 As Worksheet
```

does not recognize Worksheet

The code works fine, is just that I would like to see the methods list while coding...
Thanks!

Comment: Some of your examples are from .NET components (the Interop ones). Those are not for VBA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Excel Object Library to the references in VBA. Tools -> References, and look for Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library.
Then the declarations (and IntelliSense) should work.

Comment: @matzone I did it a bit later because my privileges are still low